# Confused by Microsoft WebSockets namespaces

Tags: .net, wcf, html, websocket

So far, in tutorials, blogs, and official documentation, I've seen:

- **Microsoft.Web.WebSockets**

  - Obtained from NuGet
  - The assembly is Microsoft.WebSockets, but the Namespace is Microsoft.Web.WebSockets
  - Last updated 14 Sept 2011
  - Contains WebSocketHandler, WebSocketCollections, WebSocketExtensions
- **System.Web.WebSockets**

  - Part of .NET 4.5 and available in Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview
  - Contains AspNetWebSocket, AspNetWebSocketContext, AspNetWebSocketOptions classes
  - [Documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.websockets(v=vs.110).aspx)
- **System.Net.WebSockets**

  - Thanks Ladislav Mrnka for pointing this one out
  - Part of .NET 4.5 and available in Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview
  - Contains WebSocket, HttpListenerWebSocketContext and more
  - [Documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets(v=vs.110).aspx)
- **System.ServiceModel.WebSockets**

  - I must have imagined I'd seen this one somewhere, can't find it now
- **Microsoft.ServiceModel.WebSockets**

  - Obtained from [html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/...](http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/prototypes/websockets/websockets/download).
  - Installed into [Program Files]\Microsoft SDKs\WCF WebSockets\11.06.22\bin
  - Contains WebSocketHost, WebSocketService, WebSocketsService classes, plus interfaces and collections
  - Last updated 22 June 2011

are these somehow different? Are some older versions?

I've always assumed the 'Microsoft.Web' namespace was used for pre-release code, but even the demos at the Build conference use this namespace, despite the fact that .NET 4.5 includes the System.Web.WebSockets namespace built in.

System.Web.WebSockets seems to have the same API as Microsoft.Web.WebSockets, but with classes and methods prefixed with AspNet.

System.ServiceModel.WebSockets is part of the WCF namespace, which also seems a sensible place to put this stuff.

Help - I'm confused. What should I be using?

Comment: Some of these namespaces are covered in Paul Batum's blog http://www.paulbatum.com/ which looks like the best source of info so far.

Comment: Much of this is now irrelevant with ASP.NET Web Api (Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi) - which can be self-hosted like WCF. It utilises Microsoft.Net.Http

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I will add little bit more to your confusion. `Microsoft.*` prefixed assemblies / namespaces are usually either very specific to some language or not part of .NET framework (shipped out of band (or prototypes)).

Assemblies / namespaces shipped with .NET framework usually start with `System.*`. There are two namespaces containing features related to WebSockets in .NET 4.5:

- `System.Net.WebSockets` - implementation of WebSockets
- `System.Web.WebSockets` - integration of WebSockets with ASP.NET

I haven't see `System.ServiceModel.WebSockets` but I think there was some prototype named `Microsoft.ServiceModel.WebSockets`

Comment: Thanks for confirming about the Microsoft.* namespace. I must have imagined the System.ServiceModel.WebSockets namespace. I'm updating the question with a little extra research.

Comment: Your answer, plus the Paul Batum blog have filled in some of the info. Since no-one else appears interested in the subject, the answer goes to you. Thanks

Comment: @GregWoods No, you were not imagining `System.ServiceModel.WebSockets` - I'm seeing it in a project created in Feb 2012, referencing a dll on the machine of a developer who has long left the company - now I gotta get it to build...

Answer (score 4):

[html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com](http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/prototypes/websockets/websockets/info):

> ...we don't plan any future updates to this prototype.

[System.Web.WebSockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.websockets):

> ...namespace contains classes that support adding WebSocket functionality to ASP.NET **Web Forms** applications.

Microsoft.Web.WebSockets:

> ...provides functionality for writing WebSocket-enabled server applications on Windows 8 using ASP.NET and WCF

---

My conclusion:

- **System.Net.WebSockets** seems like something low-level.
- **System.Web.WebSockets** need when you use ASP.NET **Web Forms**
- **Microsoft.Web.WebSockets** from NuGet looks like best choice when you use ASP.NET **MVC**

Comment: Thanks for that. I did _eventually_ work out that the very useful looking Microsoft.Web.WebSockets was Windows 8 only. Shame, it could have been useful to me.

Comment: The documentation for Microsoft.Web.WebSockets seems non-existent.  For example, how do you specify the protocol when the server selects a protocol?

Comment: In my case [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) gave me everything i need, so i stopped looking information about *.WebSockets assemblies/namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

@Greg Woods re System.ServiceModel.WebSockets: you weren't imagining it.

http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/media/1165/readme.htm

Answer (score 1):

As for the **Microsoft.Web.WebSockets** vs **System.Web.WebSockets**...

I think that:

**System.Web.WebSockets**- gives you a ***lower*** api for working with websockets

while...

**Microsoft.Web.WebSockets**- is kind of a ***higher*** api, which makes it far more easy to deal with, and also tries to mirroring the events/functions that are in the html5/javascript specification (e.g.- onerror,onopen, onmessage,onclose, send, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

This is my belief on why the naming **Microsoft.Web.WebSockets**:

"This preview package provides functionality for writing WebSocket-enabled server applications on Windows 8 using ASP.NET and WCF. Requires .NET 4.5 RC and Windows 8 RC."

It's probably a Microsoft.* named library because it was developed against Windows 8 RC. Which isn't a solid dependency so it can't be part of the official .net framework.

Of course once Windows 8 comes out they can depend on it and start releasing websockets libraries as part of the official framework. So the Microsoft.Web.WebSockets may be effectively obsoleted without ever leaving prerelease status.

What about **System.Web.WebSockets** vs **System.Net.WebSockets**?

System.Web.WebSockets: "classes that support adding WebSocket functionality to ASP.NET Web Forms applications."

Hm... Seems simple. These classes are designed to be used from ASP.NET Web Forms. Do they require Windows 8? Not sure.

System.Net.WebSockets: is something else that isn't tied to Web Forms. But it only works if you have Windows 8.

**Microsoft.ServiceModel.WebSockets**

Another old prerelease package. This one works on Windows 7!

Note: instead of worrying about what works on what platform+framework to use to get WebSockets kinda goes away you could just use SignalR instead, which will pick a transport and try to do something like websockets for you.